# Aptana 3 wont start after OS-X El Capitan update

Tags: ajax, aptana3, osx-elcapitan

I use Aptana to run a local server, so I can test my developments. Need it because I'm using AJAX.

After the update to El Capitan, AptanaStudio3 doesn't work anymore. Gives the following error:

[image]

The current topics also address this error, but they relate to the Beta version of El Capitan. The solution for that problem does not work in this case.

Anybody got an idea how I can get it running again? Or maybe a good alternative for Aptana? I dont use the code section. Only use it to run the server.

Thanks in advance.

Regards, Bas

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have same problem. I found the solution from 
http://lab.dejaworks.com/after-os-x-el-capitan-upgrade-necessary-java-update/

download this version of java: https://support.apple.com/downloads/DL1572/en_US/javaforosx.dmg
and install it.

It works for me.

Comment: This one solved it. Thanx! You saved me a lot of frustration :D

Comment: @Fathur, Link-only answers are highly discouraged on SO. If those links change in the future, this answer will become useless.