# Error Launching AptanaStudio3 in OS X El Capitan

Tags: aptana3, osx-elcapitan

I just installed Aptana Studio 3 on my iMac running El Capitan. When I try to launch it, an alert pops up with this message:

```
The JVM shared library "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/../jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib" does not contain the JNI_CreateJavaVM symbol.
```

Is there any way to fix this?

-Sam

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Aptana 3 wont start after OS-X El Capitan update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32889933/aptana-3-wont-start-after-os-x-el-capitan-update)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution at [Aptana 3 wont start after OS-X El Capitan update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32889933/aptana-3-wont-start-after-os-x-el-capitan-update)

This is no longer an issue.